# Add class to containing element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple component in react which has two buttons. All I want to do is set a class on the containing div, depending on which button is clicked...

Component (AddOn) js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

  function AddOns(props) {

  const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const [notSelected, setNotneeded] = useState(false);

  const selectAddon = () => {
    setSelected(!isSelected);
    setNotneeded(false);
  }

  const noAddon = () => {
    setNotneeded(!notSelected);
    setSelected(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="addon">
      <h2>{props.name} cover</h2>
      <h3>£{props.price} per month</h3>
      <p>{props.description} </p>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button role="radio" onClick={selectAddon} className={isSelected ? "selected" : ""}>Select this cover</button>
        <button role="radio" onClick={noAddon} className={notSelected ? "selected" : ""}>I don't need this</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddOns;
```

There's multiple components on a page...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import AddOn from './AddOns';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [extras, setExtras] = useState([
    { name: "Cover 1", price: "1.05", description: "Description goes here", groupName: "lost", groupYes: "group-1", groupNo: "group-2" },
    { name: "Cover 2", price: "2.19", description: "Description goes here", groupName: "abroad", groupYes: "group-3", groupNo: "group-4"},
    { name: "Cover 3", price: "1.53", description: "Description goes here", groupName: "farewell", groupYes: "group-5", groupNo: "group-6" }
  ])

  return (
    <div className="app">
      {extras.map(extra =>(
        <AddOn name={extra.name} price={extra.price} description={extra.description}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help much appreciated from a complete newbie to React!

Comment: Are these two buttons something like radio buttons (single choice)?

Comment: Also, I am not sure on which div you want to set class.

Comment: You want to add class to the div with the className buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use 2 states for tracking the button state. Just use one.

Please check below for detail. You can use `addonSelected` to check which button is selected.

You can set different classname depending on the state like as it is implemented for `button`.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function AddOns(props) {
  const [addonSelected, setAddonSelected] = useState(null);

  const selectAddon = () => {
    setAddonSelected(true);
  };

  const noAddon = () => {
    setAddonSelected(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`addon${
        addonSelected === true
          ? ' selected'
          : addonSelected === false
          ? ' notSelected'
          : ''
      }`}>
      <h2>{props.name} cover</h2>
      <h3>£{props.price} per month</h3>
      <p>{props.description} </p>
      <div className="buttons">
        <button
          role="radio"
          onClick={selectAddon}
          className={addonSelected === true ? 'selected' : ''}>
          Select this cover
        </button>
        <button
          role="radio"
          onClick={noAddon}
          className={addonSelected === false ? 'selected' : ''}>
          I don't need this
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddOns;
```

Comment: Thanks. So I'm try to add a class of selected or notSelected to the containing div "addon" depending on which button is clicked. Just can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: Again thanks so much for looking at this. Firstly, I need to add the class selected or notSelected to the div keeping the original addOn class (so staking them). Also the second button being selected is the initial state for the buttons where I want them to be blank, the user has to select on or the other. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it. Updated answer again.

Comment: Amazing!!!! Thanks so much for your help, it's much appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding a variable for the div class, and then change the value in both noAddon and  selectAddon function.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to keep className in state and change the state every time the user change selection.
Edit: just saw that you are trying to edit classname for a different div, edited the response as well.

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
    
      function AddOns(props) {
    
      const [buttonsClass, setButtonClass] = useState('addon');
      const [notSelected, setNotneeded] = useState(false);
    
      return (
        <div className="addon">
          <h2>{props.name} cover</h2>
          <h3>£{props.price} per month</h3>
          <p>{props.description} </p>
          <div className={buttonsClass}>
            <button role="radio" onClick={()=>{()=>setButtonClass('addon')}} className={isSelected ? "selected" : ""}>Select this cover</button>
            <button role="radio"onClick={()=>{()=>setButtonClass('noAddon')}} className={notSelected ? "selected" : ""}>I don't need this</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default AddOns;
```